# I have to compress image size without changing height and width during upload in codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am uploading number of images at a time, so its getting to much time to upload, hence i want to compress images size during upload (without changing height & width)

So please suggest me changes in my code for this.

My code snippet:

```
if($_FILES['userfile']['name'] != ""){


$allowed =  array('jpg','jpeg' ,'gif','png');
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


    $testimg =$_FILES["userfile"]["name"];

      $ppfilename = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_\w]+/", "", $testimg).".".$ext;

      $ppfilename = $ppfilename;
      $ppfilename = explode(".", $ppfilename);
      $ppnew_filename = "ad_" . $ppfilename[0] . time() . "." . $ppfilename[1];


      $ppthumb = explode(".", $ppnew_filename);
      $ppthumb = $ppthumb[0] . "_thumb". "." . $ppthumb[1];

      $_FILES["userfile"]["name"] = $ppnew_filename;
      $this->load->library("upload");

      $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options()); 

      if($this->upload->do_upload()){
          $ppimagedata = $this -> upload -> data();
          $ppnewimagename = $ppimagedata["file_name"];

          $this -> load -> library("image_lib");
          $config['image_library']   = 'gd2';
          $config['source_image']    = $ppimagedata["full_path"];
          $config['create_thumb']    = TRUE;
          $config['maintain_ratio']  = TRUE;
          $config['new_image']       = './uploads/Property/100X100/';
          $config['width']           = 100;
          $config['height']          = 100;

          $this -> image_lib -> initialize($config);
          $this -> image_lib -> resize();

          $config['new_image']    = './uploads/Property/300X300/';
          $config['width']       = 300;
          $config['height']       = 300;
          $this -> image_lib -> initialize($config);
          $this -> image_lib -> resize();

           }   

        }
        else{
          $ppnewimagename = "";
          $ppthumb = "";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must user **Image Manipulation** library and then use *quality* config

link to documentation: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html#preferences